# how get response http header?

Tags: perl, http, header, cgi, basic-authentication

my last question was about how to implement basic authentication in perl and i got my answer.
after that i tried to write my code.i used  `-status => '401 Not Authorized'` in my http header and when i try to open my programm it wants me to enter user and password.in my code i got peice of header with ENV variable that include this username and password and check if it was what i want.my problem is that when i enter user and password in authentication box like below [image: basic authentication]

i should click on cancel button to get response header!!so what is ok button here?
its my verification code

```
print header(-type => 'text/html', -status => '401 Not Authorized',
         'WWW-Authenticate' => 'Basic realm="Videos"');

print "<HTML>";
print "<HEAD>";

print "<TITLE>this is Test-Case</TITLE>";
print "</HEAD>";

my $signin = $ENV{HTTP_AUTHORIZATION};
my($basic,$userpass) = split( ' ', $signin );
($userpass,$eq) = split( '=',$userpass );
$userpass = decode_base64($userpass);
my ($user,$pass) =  split( ':',$userpass );
my $query = new CGI;
if($user eq 'aa' and $pass eq 'aa'){
show something
}
else{
     print "wrong user or pass";
}
```

i tried to use `CGI::Auth::Basic` before but it doesnt work for me and show error in module.

Thanks for your answers.

> i solved my problem after a while so i decided to tell the answer for who have this problem too.
>   you should firs check if $ENV{HTTP_AUTHORIZATION} is defined or not.if its defined you should check the user pass and if its true you print "Content-Type: text/HTML", "\n\n" that means 200ok!and if the ENV not defined you should print print header(-type => 'text/html', -status => '401 Not Authorized','WWW-Authenticate' => 'Basic realm="Videos"') to show the authentication box.

```
    $signin = $ENV{HTTP_AUTHORIZATION};
    if(defined $signin){
       check user and password here
       if(true user and password){
          print "Content-Type: text/HTML", "\n\n";
          do your all works here
       }
       else{
          wrong password
       }
    }
    else{
         print header(-type => 'text/html', -status => '401 Not   Authorized','WWW-Authenticate' => 'Basic realm="Videos"');
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks good. Did you try to output the values of each step inbetween (`$signin, $basic, $userpass, $user, $pass`) to see if everything is as you thought it would be?

Comment: @Sebastian yes i print them and all of them are correct.you know my code works fine.but after i click on ok button then cancel button!i want it to work after i click on ok button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Basic Auth works in two steps:

First step:

- Browser sends a request
- Server replies with a full HTTP Response (header, body) with HTTP status code 401
- Browser shows a (browser-specific) dialog to ask for username and password
- "OK" on that dialog typicalls starts step 2
- "Cancel" on that dialog typically shows the response body received earlier - but that depends on the browser implementation. Don't rely on it!

Second step:

- Browser re-sends the original request again, but adds an `Authorization` header
- Server checks username and password and sends a full response (header, body) with either HTTP status code 200 (OK) or 401 (in this case: "username or password wrong, try again")
- For code 401: See browser behavior for step 1
- For code 200: Show the website as usual
- Any other code is also valid: A 302 to redirect the user, a 500 to show an error, etc.

Hope that answers your question. If not, I didn't understand your problem.

Comment: this answer help me a little but my problem didnt solve.when i click on OK the original request re-send with Authorization header and browser shows dialog again,against check username and password to send a response header.when i click on cancel,response header recieved!!i dont want to show dialog again.

Comment: Do you always send a 401 response code? You must not send it if the authorization succeeded, use a 200 in this case.

Comment: i thought this is problem.when should i send 200 OK response header?can you show me a code?thanks

Comment: Move your whole `print` block below the auth check and remove that `-status => '401 Not Authorized'` in case auth was ok.

Comment: move `print header(-type => 'text/html','WWW-Authenticate' => 'Basic realm="Videos"');` to if block??i did this but dialog shows again :((